# Get buttonId on Twig file to a php class

Tags: php, symfony, button, twig, entity

I want to get the "companyPhone" when a button is clicked.

In my userStats entity the cloums are name, address and **companyPhone**, so i want to get the **companyPhone** when the button is clicked.

Button **Twig** ---

```
{% for vvv in userStatss %}
{% if vvv.condition == TRUE %} 
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs myOnbutton">On</button>
```

this is my **Script** ---

```
<script>
        $(".myOnbutton").on('click', function (e) {
         if (confirm('{% trans %}Are you sure?{% endtrans %}')) {
         $('body').addClass('load');
            var buttonId = e.currentTarget.companyPhone; 
// companyPhone is the column which is located in entity class userStatss

        //start post request
        $.post('/hello/buttondata', {companyPhone: buttonId}, function (data, err) {
         //wait for response here
            console.log("my data yippii", JSON.stringify(data));
        })
```

.....

In my **PHP** ---

```
   // route --- /hello/buttondata
    public function buttondataAction(){

                $request = $this->getRequest('companyPhone'); 
// companyPhone is the column which is located in entity class userStatss

            return new Response($request);
        }
```

Do anyone knows where i am making mistake, is it in my PHP file!
Can someone solve this problem ! Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-request-object), the following method is wrong

```
$this->getRequest('companyPhone')
```

You can get the current request object by calling `$this->getRequest()` inside an action, but it's a deprecated way to get it; add this

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
```

after the namespace declaration and then use

```
public function buttondataAction(Request $request)
{
    $companyPhone = $request->get('companyPhone');

    // Other code
}
```

I'm sorry to say that, but you should stop coding and start learning some Symfony basics as I clearly see you are missing them (expecially because this is your 3rd or 4th question about this same issue).

Answer (score 1):

Try example:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    // $_GET parameters
    $request->query->get('name');

    // $_POST parameters
    $request->request->get('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for php code debugging, and javaScript debugging. Then look up symfony documentation.